# How to use clearInterval with a click of a button that was returned from an AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

On my status page I have a div id named `errorBarGoesHere`. I have a simple AJAX call that runs every 10 seconds to check if it should display an error bar. Everything works, the error bar is displaying when I want it too, etc.

Now I just want to be able to close the error bar on command. But the button I made cannot access or see any of the other JS functions because it is on a different page. I checked the source code on the webpage and don't even see the code for the error bar when it is obviously being displayed on the page; just the `errorBarGoesHere` div tag which is blank.

Is there a way I can use that button I made to clear the interval? Code below.

Javascript

```
var setErrorBarId = window.setInterval(function(){runErrorBarAjax();}, 10000);

function runErrorBarAjax() {
    var xmlhttp = getAjaxObject();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            processErrorBarResponse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "lib/errorBar.php", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send();
}
function processErrorBarResponse(response){
    document.getElementById(\'errorBarGoesHere\').innerHTML = response;
}
```

errorBar.php

```
session_start(); // Start the session from here.

if(isset($_SESSION['errorBarError'])){
    echo '
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" media="screen" />
    <div id="errorBar">
        <div id="innertube">
            <h2><center>
                <div id="errorBarCaution"><img src="../images/caution.png" width="18" height="18"></div>'.$_SESSION['errorBarError'].'
            </center></h2>
            <input type="image" src="../images/closeButton.png" width="20" height="20" onclick="clearInt(setErrorBarId);">
        </div>
    </div>
    ';
    unset($_SESSION['errorBarError']);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with button is on different page? For removing your interval you can use `window.clearInterval(setErrorBarId);`

Comment: Yes, but my lib/errorBar.php returns content to status.php through an AJAX call. The content on lib/errorBar.php cannot clear the interval set on status.php. At least I cannot seem to get it to do so. Is there something wrong here?

Comment: You can set a special ajax response to identify for clearing interval.
This special response can you read with js and clear the interval.

Comment: I'm not sure I am following you here. Could you elaborate? Or maybe link me to an example?

Comment: Do you have already tried `window.clearInterval(setErrorBarId);`? 
I dont know what clearInt() does? But I would set your close button outside the ajax response to the static html document. Then you bind  a click handler to it within `window.clearInterval(setErrorBarId);`.

Comment: clearInt() does just that. So have the close button on status.php maybe? And appear over the error bar?

Curios, is it normal for the AJAX call to not return the code like this? Even if I create a simple alert it will not call it.

Comment: Javascript is already rendered by browser. When you do a ajax and modify the dom, javascript will not rerender your page. Please use jQuery instead of native js, there you can use document.ready statement. There you have very good ajax functions, too. By the way check your js console for errors.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).
Your Document can be..

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" media="screen" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="errorBarGoesHere"></div>
    <input id="remove" type="image" src="../images/closeButton.png" width="20" height="20" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var setErrorBarId = window.setInterval(function(){
                $("#errorBarGoesHere").load("lib/errorBar.php");
            }, 10000);
            $("#remove").on('click', function() {
                window.clearInterval(setErrorBarId);
                $(this).remove();
            });
         });
     </script>
</body>
</html>
```

errorBar.php..

```
session_start(); // Start the session from here.

if(isset($_SESSION['errorBarError'])){
    echo '
    <div id="errorBar">
        <div id="innertube">
            <h2><center>
                <div id="errorBarCaution"><img src="../images/caution.png" width="18" height="18"></div>'.$_SESSION['errorBarError'].'
            </center></h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    ';
    unset($_SESSION['errorBarError']);
}
```

Comment: This changes the behavior of the program. The remove button should only appear when the error bar appears. You've almost got the solution though. The ***real*** solution is to hide the button and show it when the error bar appears. This can be easily done with or without jQuery.

Comment: @slebetman: You are right, but i will only show another way for the problem, not an perfect detailed solution.